# Update image file via file list

Tags: typo3

Is Typo3 damn stupid or am I? I have an image uploaded with the file list and then I used this image on a page. Now I go back to the file list and upload a newer version of the file with the *same* name. But on the site the old version of the image is still visible.

I found out that Typo3 copies the file in another directory, which seems to be not synced.

1. What can I do to update a file/image this way? Or is there another way?
2. Can someone explain what the file list is for if updating files doesn’t work. In my eyes this is a stupid concept :-(

I don’t want to upload a new file and include it on the page again, because the image is used at several places and should be the same, without the need of updating it in every single place …

Comment: I believe this behaviour was changed in TYPO3 6.0 with the introduction of the file abstraction layer (FAL).

Comment: @Jost: Thanks. How can I check which version I got? I have admin access but the installation and config was done by the university's collocation centre … Further I'm completely new to typo3 and unfortunately there's nearly no support from the university …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is done on purpose. If you do not want this, you have to either update to 6.x or use the extension dam.

The reason for this behavior is that editors cannot change content on websites that they do not have access to. The files are always copied, therefore you have a file for each record.
Also this eases working with workspaces.

You can find out your version by looking into the page title after login in to the backend. The version is displayed in the title.

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain why the developers decide to to this, maybe there’s a clever thing in it I can’t see …? Unfortunately I found “You are using version 4.7.11” in the about menu. So the only option is to use DAM, right? Is there a dummy guide to DAM?

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I’m not allowed to install extensions myself. :-/

Comment: The extension DAM is no longer developed for TYPO3 >= 6.0. Therefore I would suggest not to use DAM but to switch to TYPO3 6.1.

Comment: @lorenz: OK, thanks. Are there any other ways to keep the multiply used image file in sync? Updating to 6.x won’T happen in the near future :-(

Comment: The only way to achieve that is using DAM and then again using dam_ttcontent for the images. In DAM, you can replace files.